# Why does cv2 mask + imwrite reduce image detail?

Tags: python, opencv, tiff, filesize

I have a 1.17 Gb tiff ('heatmap') which I want to crop to the outline of another 425.7 Mb tiff ('pavement'). The heatmap contains subtle color shading that I want to keep in the final image. I'm using a `bitwise_and` operation to apply the pavement image as a mask, and using `cv2.imwrite` to save. But the resulting tiff lacks the subtle shading and is only 10.5 Mb. That seems like a big reduction in size and is probably why the final image has less detail.

What can I do to retain the subtle shading of the input in the output image?

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

heatmapfile  = "heatmap.tif"
pavementfile = "pavement.tif"
output       = "masked_heatmap.tif"

heatmap  = cv2.imread(heatmapfile,-1)
pavement = cv2.imread(pavementfile,0)

# apply thresholding to create mask
ret, binimg = cv2.threshold(pavement,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# make binary image same size as heatmap, needed for bitwise_and
bin_4ch = cv2.cvtColor(binimg,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)

# mask the heatmap and save
hm_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(heatmap,bin4ch)
cv2.imwrite(output, hm_masked)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at OpenCV's [`ImwriteFlags`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac), especially those regarding TIFF images?

Comment: @HansHirse: thanks for the tip! There is indeed a flag for TIFF compression, and the default is LZW: `IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION `. That explains the change in file size but not the change in appearance. Shouldn't the uncompressed tiff look the same as the original?